# Goto command not working if run batch file from c: drive or desktop

Tags: windows, batch-file, goto

I have small batch file to upgrade my program, if I run this batch file from any drive except `C:` drive  it works correctly.

I'm trying this command

```
@ECHO OFF

IF EXIST C:\TWA\DRV.TXT GOTO TST1
DIR *.EXE /P
PAUSE

:TST1
DIR ASHOK.ZIP
PAUSE
```

*I'm working on Windows 8.1*

Comment: SHIFT KEY STUCK SEND HELP

Comment: First of all, please don't shout at us. Secondly, what do you mean by "its not working properly"? What errors (if any) do you get?

Comment: Does C:\TWA\DRV.TXT exist?   What result are you seeing from other drives?  What result are you seeing from the C: drive?

Answer (score 0):

I would add a `goto end` to avoid running the TST1 section if `DRV.TXT` is not 
found.

```
@ECHO OFF

IF EXIST C:\TWA\DRV.TXT GOTO TST1
DIR *.EXE /P
goto end
PAUSE

:TST1
DIR ASHOK.ZIP
PAUSE

:END
echo Finished!
pause
```